# Why is video taking so long to load? And then not playing

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, html5-video

I'm writing Python/Django app and I've enabled users to load video files which are stored in the `/media/` directory.  When I then try and play those files back the html seems to be trying to download the whole file first and even when it's done that it doesn't play the video.

HTML upload form

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/upload_file/" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <table align="center">{{ form }}</table>
    <input name="cid" hidden value="{{course.id}}" type="text">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Upload Content</button>
</form>
```

Python view

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModelFormWithFileField(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            form.save()
            msg = "Successful upload"
        else:
            msg = "Invalid form"
    else:
        msg = "File not loaded"
    return display_course(request, msg=msg, course = Course.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('cid'))))
```

HTML Play

```
<video width="854" height="480" controls>
     <source src="../media/{{module.module_key.url}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the video point exactly to` ../media/{{module.module_key.url}}`? Have you tried opening it directly using the address bar?

Comment: The address given in the html page maps to the exact file location xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/media/profile/video.mp4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Django's built-in server does not support mp4 file playback (need some tricks).

Secondly, some mp4 files are not streamable.

You can try:

1. use nginx or other web servers to serve the file
2. make sure the mp4 file is streamable.